# Does the Game Ban text go away when it lifts?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-go-overwatch

If I get a cheater ban from Overwatch for ~1 year, will the text of "1 game bans on record" go away when the ban lifts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VAC bans are recorded on the user's Steam profile, and will be **permanently visible** to *all other users*. Even if your profile is set on "Private", anybody can see the ban records.

Overwatch bans are **Game bans** ; Game bans are managed by game developers (in that case, Valve). They are recorded on your profile all the same.

Comment: and as far as i know there is no possible way to lift the ban or get your account unbaned

Comment: Indeed. [Steam support about VAC :](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7849-Radz-6869) `All VAC bans are permanent - Valve has a zero-tolerance policy for cheating and will not lift VAC bans under any circumstances.` But since that isn't part of the question, I didn't add it.

Comment: Not VAC, I'm talking about game bans by Overwatch, which take about ~1 year to lift.

Comment: Ugh, sorry for making this not an answer, but it is wrong, only permanent game-bans/overwatch bans are displayed: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/9/620712364027233611/

Comment: Are you banned, or not ?